# how to get randomize the json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a table whose data is coming from a jsonfile. Let say, the json file have 10 sets of data. but in my table i want randomize the no. of data.
This is my json

```
 {
"Payload": [
    {
        "srcFileName": "02-Blk65536Alk_CCN1-9967-20150521223150-12975",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "04-Blk65536Blk_GGSN1-9967-20150521223150-10375",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "01-BlkWE536Xlk_CCN1-9967-20150521223150-10575",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "02-Blk65236Blk_SGSN1-9967-20150521223150-15775",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "04-BlkDF5236Blk_CCN1-9967-20150521223150-15775",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "05-Blk65236Blk_CCN1-9967-20150521223150-15775",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "08-Blk65236Blk_CCN1-9967-20150521223150-15775",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    },
    {
        "srcFileName": "02-Blk65236Blk_SASN1-9967-20150521223150-15775",
        "srcFileSize": "1048576"
    }
 ]}
```

Normally if I want to fetch all data of the json i wrote that like

```
 $.getJSON('resources/json/monitor_precessed_files.json', function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data.Payload, function (index, value) {
            $('#processed_files').append('  <li title="' + value.srcFileSize + " " + '"class="list-group-item"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span><small>'
                    + value.srcFileName + '</small></li>');
        });
 });
```

But I dont want the all data. i want the no of data sholud be randomize. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a random element from array using instead of using `$.each`

```
$.getJSON('resources/json/monitor_precessed_files.json', function(data) {
    var len = data.Payload.length;

    //Set no of items to fetch
    var itemsToFetch = Math.floor(Math.random()*len); 

    //Fetch random items
    for(var i=0; i <= itemsToFetch; i++){

        //Get Random element
        var payload = data.Payload[Math.floor(Math.random()*len)];
        $('#processed_files').append('  <li title="' + payload.srcFileSize 
            + " " + '"class="list-group-item"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span><small>'
            + payload.srcFileName 
            + '</small></li>');
    }
});
```

Comment: With ur example I get only one random data. actually i want like 1st tym I got 3 rows, then next tym 5 and next tym 1 like that

Comment: I want the number of data to be randomize.

Comment: Thank u very much @Satpal.. I was also trying like this, but could not make that happen.. Thank you